# R studio console not viewing Stata Variables

Tags: r

i would like to view stata variables in R studio Console, i have Installed LessR package but to know avail

Tried to install Packman & LessR packages, i am only seeing the Variables in Global Environment

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I don´t know if I understand the question. I supose you have load a stata dataset with haven library. May be you want to write in console: `str(data)`